# How to understand this LSTM example?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I was trying to go along with [this tutorial](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/lstm-python-stock-market#comment-1243). And I got stuck on this part of code, accompanied by this picture:

```
class DataGeneratorSeq(object):

    def __init__(self,prices,batch_size,num_unroll):
        self._prices = prices
        self._prices_length = len(self._prices) - num_unroll
        self._batch_size = batch_size
        self._num_unroll = num_unroll
        self._segments = self._prices_length //self._batch_size
        self._cursor = [offset * self._segments for offset in range(self._batch_size)]
```

[image]

I am confused by what it going on there. Why are there what seems to be batches of other batches? And by what logic are they being generated?

I even tried making a small example to try to figure it out, but I still have no idea what is going on:

```
batch_size = 6
prices = [10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19]
num_unroll = 4
prices_length = len(prices) - num_unroll
print('prices_length =', prices_length)
segments = prices_length // batch_size
print('segments =', segments)
cursor = [offset * segments for offset in range(batch_size)]
print('cursor :', cursor, '\n')

dg2 = DataGeneratorSeq(prices, batch_size, num_unroll)
u_data2, u_labels2 = dg2.unroll_batches()

for ui,(dat,lbl) in enumerate(zip(u_data2,u_labels2)):   
    print('\n\nUnrolled index %d'%ui)
    dat_ind = dat
    lbl_ind = lbl
    print('\tInputs: ',dat )
    print('\n\tOutput:',lbl)
```

Output:

```
prices_length = 6
segments = 1
cursor : [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5] 

b:  0 ,  [10.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
b:  1 ,  [10. 11.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
b:  2 ,  [10. 11. 12.  0.  0.  0.]
b:  3 ,  [10. 11. 12. 13.  0.  0.]
b:  4 ,  [10. 11. 12. 13. 14.  0.]
b:  5 ,  [10. 11. 12. 13. 14. 14.]
ui:  0 ,  [array([10., 11., 12., 13., 14., 14.], dtype=float32)]
ui:  0 ,  [array([14., 13., 15., 16., 16., 17.], dtype=float32)]
b:  0 ,  [11.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
b:  1 ,  [11. 12.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
b:  2 ,  [11. 12. 13.  0.  0.  0.]
b:  3 ,  [11. 12. 13. 14.  0.  0.]
b:  4 ,  [11. 12. 13. 14. 12.  0.]
b:  5 ,  [11. 12. 13. 14. 12. 15.]
ui:  1 ,  [array([10., 11., 12., 13., 14., 14.], dtype=float32), array([11., 12., 13., 14., 12., 15.], dtype=float32)]
ui:  1 ,  [array([14., 13., 15., 16., 16., 17.], dtype=float32), array([14., 15., 16., 16., 16., 18.], dtype=float32)]
b:  0 ,  [12.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
b:  1 ,  [12. 13.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
b:  2 ,  [12. 13. 14.  0.  0.  0.]
b:  3 ,  [12. 13. 14. 13.  0.  0.]
b:  4 ,  [12. 13. 14. 13. 13.  0.]
b:  5 ,  [12. 13. 14. 13. 13. 10.]
ui:  2 ,  [array([10., 11., 12., 13., 14., 14.], dtype=float32), array([11., 12., 13., 14., 12., 15.], dtype=float32), array([12., 13., 14., 13., 13., 10.], dtype=float32)]
ui:  2 ,  [array([14., 13., 15., 16., 16., 17.], dtype=float32), array([14., 15., 16., 16., 16., 18.], dtype=float32), array([16., 15., 16., 17., 16., 11.], dtype=float32)]
b:  0 ,  [13.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
b:  1 ,  [13. 14.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
b:  2 ,  [13. 14. 12.  0.  0.  0.]
b:  3 ,  [13. 14. 12. 14.  0.  0.]
b:  4 ,  [13. 14. 12. 14. 14.  0.]
b:  5 ,  [13. 14. 12. 14. 14. 11.]
ui:  3 ,  [array([10., 11., 12., 13., 14., 14.], dtype=float32), array([11., 12., 13., 14., 12., 15.], dtype=float32), array([12., 13., 14., 13., 13., 10.], dtype=float32), array([13., 14., 12., 14., 14., 11.], dtype=float32)]
ui:  3 ,  [array([14., 13., 15., 16., 16., 17.], dtype=float32), array([14., 15., 16., 16., 16., 18.], dtype=float32), array([16., 15., 16., 17., 16., 11.], dtype=float32), array([15., 18., 15., 18., 15., 12.], dtype=float32)]
 ----------  [array([10., 11., 12., 13., 14., 14.], dtype=float32), array([11., 12., 13., 14., 12., 15.], dtype=float32), array([12., 13., 14., 13., 13., 10.], dtype=float32), array([13., 14., 12., 14., 14., 11.], dtype=float32)] --------------
[(array([10., 11., 12., 13., 14., 14.], dtype=float32), array([14., 13., 15., 16., 16., 17.], dtype=float32)), (array([11., 12., 13., 14., 12., 15.], dtype=float32), array([14., 15., 16., 16., 16., 18.], dtype=float32)), (array([12., 13., 14., 13., 13., 10.], dtype=float32), array([16., 15., 16., 17., 16., 11.], dtype=float32)), (array([13., 14., 12., 14., 14., 11.], dtype=float32), array([15., 18., 15., 18., 15., 12.], dtype=float32))]
<enumerate object at 0x7fb354a12a68>
 ----------  [array([10., 11., 12., 13., 14., 14.], dtype=float32), array([11., 12., 13., 14., 12., 15.], dtype=float32), array([12., 13., 14., 13., 13., 10.], dtype=float32), array([13., 14., 12., 14., 14., 11.], dtype=float32)] --------------
```

Why is `prices_length` calculated as the total length of the prices array minus this mysterious unroll number? Is seems like `num_unroll` is the number of batches, but the picture confuses me. And what is this `segments` variable?

And I've read a whole bunch of other tutorials on LSTM, but none of them are this in-depth. And I feel like I understand how it's supposed to work in theory, just the LSTM in itself, but I can't figure this code out.

Here is the entire class code:

```
class DataGeneratorSeq(object):

    def __init__(self,prices,batch_size,num_unroll):
        self._prices = prices
        self._prices_length = len(self._prices) - num_unroll
        self._batch_size = batch_size
        self._num_unroll = num_unroll
        self._segments = self._prices_length //self._batch_size
        self._cursor = [offset * self._segments for offset in range(self._batch_size)]

    def next_batch(self):

        batch_data = np.zeros((self._batch_size),dtype=np.float32)
        batch_labels = np.zeros((self._batch_size),dtype=np.float32)

        for b in range(self._batch_size):
            if self._cursor[b]+1>=self._prices_length:
                #self._cursor[b] = b * self._segments
                self._cursor[b] = np.random.randint(0,(b+1)*self._segments)

            batch_data[b] = self._prices[self._cursor[b]]
            batch_labels[b]= self._prices[self._cursor[b]+np.random.randint(0,5)]

            self._cursor[b] = (self._cursor[b]+1)%self._prices_length

        return batch_data,batch_labels

    def unroll_batches(self):

        unroll_data,unroll_labels = [],[]
        init_data, init_label = None,None
        for ui in range(self._num_unroll):

            data, labels = self.next_batch()    

            unroll_data.append(data)
            unroll_labels.append(labels)

        return unroll_data, unroll_labels

    def reset_indices(self):
        for b in range(self._batch_size):
            self._cursor[b] = np.random.randint(0,min((b+1)*self._segments,self._prices_length-1))



dg = DataGeneratorSeq(train_data,5,5)
u_data, u_labels = dg.unroll_batches()

for ui,(dat,lbl) in enumerate(zip(u_data,u_labels)):   
    print('\n\nUnrolled index %d'%ui)
    dat_ind = dat
    lbl_ind = lbl
    print('\tInputs: ',dat )
    print('\n\tOutput:',lbl)
```

EDIT: ok, so I read more about unrolling a LSTM network and the num_unroll var makes sense now. So it's just iterating over however many data points we want to look back and feeding them to the network while updating it at every step.

But still not sure what the "segments" are and why some randomness is introduced. Doesn't that defeat the point of predicting based on the previous n points?